# Queuing threads in asp.net forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

So I have a .net forms application which allows users to review a pdf and the click a button which calls a thread and converts the PDF to a JPG file.

This works a treat... as long as the button is only clicked once every 5 seconds or so... is there a way to queue these threads up so that they only run every 20 seconds?

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
private Thread workerThread = null;

private void HeavyOperation()           
{
   MagickImage image = new MagickImage(string.Format(@"c:\Portal\Portal\Scratch\PendingPDF\{0}",PDF));
   image.Write(string.Format("C:\\ECG\\PendingPDF\\{0}.jpg", Id));

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(HeavyOperation));
   this.workerThread.Start();
}
```

The error has something to do with ghost script running multiple instances and trying to run temp files.

**Exception Message**

> iisexpress.exe: PDFDelegateFailed `[ghostscript library 9.16] -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r72x72" -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 "-sOutputFile=C:/Users/FLYNNH~1.CAR/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-10484A-8hpdtwYDYR%d" "-fC:/Users/FLYNNH~1.CAR/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-10484B8rfiCrx57IP" "-fC:/Users/FLYNNH~1.CAR/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-10484yu7IrjEMvrha": (null)' @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/788

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scott Hanselman recommend to use for such tasks [HangFire](http://hangfire.io/)

It is nuget package that you can use for scheduling background jobs in asp.net.